# Error while Checking custom package " Error in library("PHit") : there is no package called 'PHit' "

Tags: r, rcpp, devtools, r-package

I'm using Rcpp to convert a bunch of functions written in C++ into a R package and I've managed to get past all the bugs in the code, but when I run the check, all the code checks out, but when it loads my package "PHit" it gives me that error and halts Execution

This is Windows 10 and I'm using R 3.6 in R Studio.  I'm building my package in my works Share drive so others have access if that makes a difference.  I've tried reinstalling the package, I've checked the .libpaths() and every solution offered for every similar question.  The packages in those questions were external such as dplyr

```
  > pkgname <- "PHit"
  > source(file.path(R.home("share"), "R", "examples-header.R"))
  > options(warn = 1)
  > options(pager = "console")
  > base::assign(".ExTimings", "PHit-Ex.timings", pos = 'CheckExEnv')
  > base::cat("name\tuser\tsystem\telapsed\n", file=base::get(".ExTimings", pos = 'CheckExEnv'))
  > base::assign(".format_ptime",
  + function(x) {
  +   if(!is.na(x[4L])) x[1L] <- x[1L] + x[4L]
  +   if(!is.na(x[5L])) x[2L] <- x[2L] + x[5L]
  +   options(OutDec = '.')
  +   format(x[1L:3L], digits = 7L)
  + },
  + pos = 'CheckExEnv')
  > 
  > ### * </HEADER>
  > library('PHit')
  Error in library("PHit") : there is no package called 'PHit'
  Execution halted
```

I expect it to recognize the package because I can load it in the console just fine although it only contains one out of the several functions that should be available, if it completely compiled as it should

Comment: How are you installing `PHit`? It's needs to be installed before you can all `library()` to load it. Are you using `devtools` to create your package? `devtools::load_all()` does roughly the same thing with your project as `library()` does for installed packages.

Comment: I am not sure what the code you show is supposed to do -- or are you trying to avoid package loading?  Well, guess what -- that is related to your error.  You may never have installed the code in your R package library directory.  Can you try `R CMD build ...` aimed at your source directory, and then install the source file with `R CMD INSTALL ...` ?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  That is the error and code generated from running the devtools::check function.  My goal is to just get this whole package to work and compile.  There are at least 20 functions written in C++ and so far only one is showing in the RcppExports.cpp file

Comment: I have never seen such code being generated by `devtools:check`. Anyway, are the functions missing from `RcppExports.cpp` marked as `// [[Rcpp::export]`? Did you call `Rcpp::compileAttributes()`?